# Segfault during JNI Java object instantiation

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

(I am aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337360/jni-segfaults-creating-new-object). This is a separate issue.)

I am getting a segfault when instantiating a Java object from C++ JNI code.

Here is the segfault:

```
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2c7ba13548, pid=2809, tid=139829052933888
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x559548]  Dictionary::add_protection_domain(int, unsigned int, instanceKlassHandle, ClassLoaderData*, Handle, Thread*)+0x128
```

Here's the relevant portion of the stack from the hs_err file:

```
Stack: [0x00007f2c7cf78000,0x00007f2c7d079000],  sp=0x00007f2c7d0760c0,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x559548]  Dictionary::add_protection_domain(int, unsigned int, instanceKlassHandle, ClassLoaderData*, Handle, Thread*)+0x128
V  [libjvm.so+0xa1f4e2]  SystemDictionary::validate_protection_domain(instanceKlassHandle, Handle, Handle, Thread*)+0x142
V  [libjvm.so+0xa230d4]  SystemDictionary::resolve_instance_class_or_null(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, Thread*)+0x3c4
V  [libjvm.so+0xa24a13]  SystemDictionary::resolve_or_fail(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, bool, Thread*)+0x33
V  [libjvm.so+0x4ea4f8]  ConstantPool::klass_at_impl(constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x158
V  [libjvm.so+0x4efbd0]  ConstantPool::klass_ref_at(int, Thread*)+0xa0
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e0eb1]  LinkResolver::resolve_pool(KlassHandle&, Symbol*&, Symbol*&, KlassHandle&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x71
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e7206]  LinkResolver::resolve_invokeinterface(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0xa6
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e9ad0]  LinkResolver::resolve_invoke(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Bytecodes::Code, Thread*)+0xb0
V  [libjvm.so+0x67a972]  InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke(JavaThread*, Bytecodes::Code)+0x1b2
j  [my-package].NativeRef$X509_ATTRIBUTE.<init>(J)V+21
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c432b]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x41b
V  [libjvm.so+0x6d943b]  jni_NewObjectV+0x2ab
C  [[my-so].so+0x2b855]  JNIEnv_::NewObject(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+0xb5
C  [[my-so].so+0x7d31e]  _jobject* newNativeRef<UniquePtr<x509_attributes_st, X509_ATTRIBUTE_Delete> >(JNIEnv_*, char const*, UniquePtr<x509_attributes_st, X509_ATTRIBUTE_Delete>*, bool)+0x352
```

Quick overview of my library: my code wraps around OpenSSL to provide Java applications access to OpenSSL via the JCA API. (Note: not all written from scratch. Some code originated in [Conscrypt](https://github.com/google/conscrypt), the Android library which performs a similar function.)

I have a number of nearly-identical classes (simple Java wrappers of a native pointer which automatically free the native object from within the finalize() method) which all extend a class called NativeRef. (Partial code is below.)

So I created a common native function (newNativeRef()) to take the native pointer and instantiate a Java object, passing the native pointer to the constructor. This function has been in use for over a year and has been very heavily tested. I've had no problems so far. (Partial code is below)

But I'm now writing a new JNI function which calls newNativeRef() and gives the segfault.

Here is the invocation in my new JNI function that I'm currently writing:

```
ret = newNativeRef<Unique_X509_ATTRIBUTE>(env, CLASS_NR_X509_ATTRIBUTE, &attr, false);
```

attr is a simple smart pointer (Unique_X509_ATTRIBUTE) wrapping around the basic pointer to the OpenSSL X509_ATTRIBUTE object.

CLASS_NR_X509_ATTRIBUTE is defined as "[my-package]/NativeRef$X509_ATTRIBUTE"

Here is the definition of Unique_X509_ATTRIBUTE:

```
struct X509_ATTRIBUTE_Delete {
    void operator()(X509_ATTRIBUTE* p) const {
        X509_ATTRIBUTE_free(p);
    }
};
typedef UniquePtr<X509_ATTRIBUTE, X509_ATTRIBUTE_Delete> Unique_X509_ATTRIBUTE;
```

Here is the relevant (trimmed down) code from UniquePtr

```
template <typename T, typename D = DefaultDelete<T> >
class UniquePtr {
public:
    // Construct a new UniquePtr, taking ownership of the given raw pointer.
    explicit UniquePtr(T* ptr = (T*) NULL) : mPtr(ptr) {
    }

    T* get() const { return mPtr; }

    // Returns the raw pointer and hands over ownership to the caller.
    // The pointer will not be deleted by UniquePtr.
    T* release() CJ_ATTRIBUTE(((warn_unused_result))){
        T* result = mPtr;
        mPtr = NULL;
        return result;
    }

    // Takes ownership of the given raw pointer.
    // If this smart pointer previously owned a different raw pointer, that
    // raw pointer will be freed.
    void reset(T* ptr = (T*) NULL) {
        if (ptr != mPtr) {
            D()(mPtr); // Basically, this calls X509_ATTRIBUTE_free(mPtr)
            mPtr = ptr;
        }
    }

private:
    // The raw pointer.
    T* mPtr;
};
```

Here is the function where the segfault occurs:

```
template<typename T> jobject newNativeRef(JNIEnv* env, const char* className,
        T* addr) {

    jclass clazz;
    jobject object = JNIHandle_NULL;

    try {

        clazz = env->FindClass(className);
        [snip - error-checking]

        jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>",
                NATIVE_FUNC_SIG(SIG_VOID, SIG_LONG));

        jlong jaddr = JNIHandle_NULL;

        if (addr != NULL) {
            jaddr =
                    static_cast<jlong>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>((*addr).get()));
        }

        // This line generates the segfault.
        object = env->NewObject(clazz, constructor, jaddr);

        if (addr != NULL) {
            // Ownership of the pointer has been passed to the Java object
            OWNERSHIP_TRANSFERRED((*addr));
        }

    [snip - error handling]

    return object;
}
```

NATIVE_FUNC_SIG(SIG_VOID, SIG_LONG) evaluates to "(J)V"

Here's the Java class for wrapping pointers to X509_ATTRIBUTE objects (i.e. the class we're trying to create an instance of):

```
public static class X509_ATTRIBUTE extends NativeRef {
    public X509_ATTRIBUTE(long ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    protected void opensslFree() {
        [Native-function-class].X509_ATTRIBUTE_free(this);
    }
}
```

And the NativeRef super-class (trimmed down):

```
public abstract class NativeRef {

    transient volatile long context = 0L;

    public NativeRef(long ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try {
            free();
        } finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void free() {
        try {
            if (isValid()) {
                opensslFree();
            }
        } finally {
            context = 0L;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void opensslFree();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**[edit]**

Interestingly, the crash doesn't seem to be specific to this newNativeRef() call. After commenting out the newNativeRef() calls, the same segfault shows up the next time the JNI attempts to instantiate a Java object (in this case, a Java exception).

I've even seen the same segfault with stacktraces that don't include any of my JNI code. Here is the hs_err stacktrace from one such crash:

```
Stack: [0x00007f8535bf7000,0x00007f8535cf8000],  sp=0x00007f8535cf5bf0,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x559548]  Dictionary::add_protection_domain(int, unsigned int, instanceKlassHandle, ClassLoaderData*, Handle, Thread*)+0x128
V  [libjvm.so+0xa1f4e2]  SystemDictionary::validate_protection_domain(instanceKlassHandle, Handle, Handle, Thread*)+0x142
V  [libjvm.so+0xa230d4]  SystemDictionary::resolve_instance_class_or_null(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, Thread*)+0x3c4
V  [libjvm.so+0xa24a13]  SystemDictionary::resolve_or_fail(Symbol*, Handle, Handle, bool, Thread*)+0x33
V  [libjvm.so+0x4ea4f8]  ConstantPool::klass_at_impl(constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x158
V  [libjvm.so+0x89d141]  Method::fast_exception_handler_bci_for(methodHandle, KlassHandle, int, Thread*)+0x141
V  [libjvm.so+0x6774dd]  InterpreterRuntime::exception_handler_for_exception(JavaThread*, oopDesc*)+0x32d
j  CertRequest.setAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+32
j  MyApp.run()V+176
j  MyApp.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c3692]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x362
V  [libjvm.so+0x6e009a]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x17a
C  [libjli.so+0x7bcc]  JavaMain+0x80c
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7dc5]  start_thread+0xc5

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  CertRequest.setAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+32
j  MyApp.run()V+176
j  MyApp.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an earlier function was corrupting some memory, which would cause semi-random errors during the next Java invocation from JNI.